# Define size for `get_post_gallery_images`, they seem to have been resized to 150x150

Tags: gallery, images

I'm using `get_post_gallery_images` and it's spitting images out as 150x150. It doesn't look like it takes a size parameter, so I assumed it would just spit out the largest image or preferably one of my defined sizes. 150x150 is too small though, is there somewhere I can declare what size gallery images I want?

For instance I'm doing:

```
<?php
$gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post ); 
foreach ($gallery as $img) { ?>
    <li><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" /></li>
<?php } ?>
```

All of these images are coming out as 150x150, is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want `get_post_gallery_images` to give you *full* size images, you can use the following:

```
// Use full size gallery images for the next gallery shortcode: 
add_filter( 'shortcode_atts_gallery', 'wpse_141896_shortcode_atts_gallery' );
// Your code:
$gallery = get_post_gallery_images( $post ); 
foreach ($gallery as $img) { ?>
    <li><img src="<?php echo $img; ?>" /></li>
<?php }
```

where

```
/**
 * Set the size attribute to 'full' in the next gallery shortcode.
 */
function wpse_141896_shortcode_atts_gallery( $out )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    $out['size'] = 'full';
    return $out;
}
```

In this example we remove the filter after using it once, so it will not affect your other galleries.

This way you don't have to include the `size="full"` attribute in your gallery shortcodes,

Comment: Thanks, I came across this after some google'n and used it :) it worked nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Check: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size
WordPress will create a copy with desired size, and then you just display it.

Comment: Please explain how this is relavent to the question

Comment: @PieterGoosen Read last sentence in the question, you know what function is doing I do not have to explain you that. And there is an code example in a link that I have posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working within a template file, this code should work.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery size="full"]'); ?>
```