# Get ORIGINAL image links from get_post_gallery

Tags: customization, gallery

I use `get_post_gallery( WP_Post, false )` to get gallery data because I build gallery HTML myself.

However strangely it only gives list of ID's and list of thumb-urls.

What is the best way to retrieve original gallery images links? Is it safe to rely on `WIDTHxHEIGHT` filename postfix and just remove it by PHP replace?

Or should I use `wp_get_attachment_image_src()` and put every ID through that? That just does not seem right ... I think there should be a way how to, at least, do this at one request ...

...or is there some better way?

If some is interested in the "brutal" `foreach`+`wp_get_attachment_image_src()` way :

**ATTENTION:** Works properly only on NON-random galleries!

```
$page = ...; //get page/post object / ID here ...

//using get_post_gallery, get_post_gallery_images provides only thumb urls
//get_post_gallery args:  WP Post/ID, HTML => true means give ready html, false means original data (array)
$gallery = get_post_gallery( $page, false ); //get FIRST gallery of $page
$output = "";
if( ! empty($gallery) ){ //if gallery was found
  //strangely, IDs are served as a STRING (at least in WP 4.5)
  if( !is_array($gallery['ids']) ) $gallery['ids'] = explode(',', $gallery['ids']);

  $output .= '<div class="custom-gallery">';
  foreach( $gallery['ids'] as $order => &$image_attachment_id ){
    $output .= 
       '<a href="'.wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_attachment_id, 'full')[0].'">'
        .'<img src="'.$gallery['src'][$order].'">'
      .'</a>'
    ;
  }    
  $output .= '</div>';
}
//do something with $output here ...
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141907/26350) can help?

Comment: You seem to have worked out (partial) solution already. If you get IDs then going through API for what you want is pretty much the way.

Comment: @Rarst ...it's messed up if only way is to make so much calls :/ thanks for opinion though...

Comment: @jave.web I just tested and I get the full image sizes, with `get_post_gallery()` by using the filter in the linked answer.

Comment: @birgire Sorry I've overlooked that... anyway thats a hacky-wacky solution, but it might be the only current one ... sadly... Thanks anyway! :-)

Comment: I looked into WP gallery codes (unrelated problem) and I found out that WP does the same, it just foreaches the wp_get_attachment_image_src....